# Magento 2.3.3 - 502 Bad Gateway - Centos - Nginx

Tags: error, installation, nginx, magento2.3.3, centos

After placed Magento 2.3.3 files to usr/share/nginx/html/magento & created database then run following,

```
php bin/magento setup:install --base-url=http://192.168.1.64/magento --db-host=localhost --db-name="magento" --db-user="root" --db-password="" --admin-firstname="abc" --admin-lastname="abc" --admin-email=abc@gmail.com --admin-user="magento" --admin-password="magento" --language="en_US" --currency="INR" --timezone="Asia/Kolkata" --use-rewrites="1"
```

***and also edit etc/nginx/conf.d/magento.conf***

```
upstream fastcgi_backend {
  server unix:/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
}

server {

  listen 8091;
  server_name http://192.168.1.64:8091/;
  set $MAGE_ROOT /usr/share/nginx/html/magento;
  include /usr/share/nginx/html/magento/nginx.conf.sample;
}
```

> Screenshot : **https://snipboard.io/K5t9Qm.jpg**

How to solve 502 bad gateway error?

Note : `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` -> test.php inside /usr/share/nginx/html php info page return 502 bad gateway error.

Answer (score 2):

you see this config part:

```
upstream fastcgi_backend {
  server unix:/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
}
```

this is where your php-fpm is listening.
please check your php-fpm config, it must be the same socket path, with correct user `read` permissions.
or change it to `ip:port` - `127.0.0.1:9000`

Comment: After updated in /etc/nginx/conf.d/magento.conf => https://justpaste.it/6oxl8  what is this error => https://justpaste.it/2jbsm

Comment: this is not error, just debug message